How to update android widget by receiving push notification
I want to update my android widget when push notification received (even if my app process killed). There is any ways to do it, or I can update widget only by tap on it?
Now I implemented firebase push notifications in my Xamarin Forms project.
Application.cs at my Android proj:
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Plugin.FirebasePushNotification;
using System;

namespace appslovo.Droid
{
    [Application]
    public class MainApplication : Application
    {
        public MainApplication(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transer) : base(handle, transer)
        {
        }

        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            base.OnCreate();

            //Set the default notification channel for your app when running Android Oreo
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.O)
            {
                //Change for your default notification channel id here
              FirebasePushNotificationManager.DefaultNotificationChannelId = "FirebasePushNotificationChannel";

                //Change for your default notification channel name here
                FirebasePushNotificationManager.DefaultNotificationChannelName = "New posts";
                
               FirebasePushNotificationManager.DefaultNotificationChannelImportance = NotificationImportance.Max;
            }

            //If debug you should reset the token each time.
#if DEBUG
           // FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(this, true);
#else
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(this, false);
#endif

            //Handle notification when app is closed here
            CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationReceived += (s, p) =>
           {

// *??????probably i need to write something there?????????*
           };
        }
    }
}

Also I have a widget.cs in Android folder(updating by tap on it by default):
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Android.App;
using Android.Appwidget;
using Android.Content;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Content.PM;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using Android.Widget;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace appslovo.Droid
{

    [BroadcastReceiver(Label = "Widget", Exported =true)]
    [IntentFilter(new string[] { "android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" })]
    [IntentFilter(new string[] { "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" })]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionTimeTick })]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionApplicationRestrictionsChanged })]
    [IntentFilter(new string[] { "android.intent.action.TIME_CHANGED" })]
    
    [IntentFilter(new [] { Intent.ActionAppError })]
    [MetaData("android.appwidget.provider", Resource = "@xml/appwidgetprovider")]
    public class AppWidget : AppWidgetProvider
    {
        public async override void OnUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds)
        {
            
                var me = new ComponentName(context_wdgt, Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(AppWidget)).Name);
                appWidgetManager_wdgt.UpdateAppWidget(me, BuildRemoteViews(context_wdgt, appWidgetIds_wdgt, ss, nn, tt));
            
            
        }
...
}

I think I should call widget activity in  CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationReceived += (s, p) => {}
but I don't know how to call widget update function from it.
